# Setting up WSO2 GREG with Oracle: permission to dbgreg user

Tags: oracle11g, wso2

I am trying to set up GREG 4.5.3 with Oracle 11.2.0.1. 
The documentation http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Setting+up+with+Oracle (step 3) ask for creating a user and grants it dba role.

Is it needed that the user has dba role? Can I assign the user to a more restrictive role?

Dba role is forbiden by our dba department for application users.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It's not necessary to grant the dba role always to your database user in order to configure the registry datasource. Typically, you would only need to grant connect, create session and database table level privileges such as SELECT, INSERT, etc. to your database user to be able to use it in the registry datasource configuration.

Cheers,
Prabath